# Require Function onEdit Reject Input code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Have a simple Function onEdit code as below. Similar to what the 'Data Validation' UI option does.
I need to know alongside Active sheet build(), to also Reject Input anything else that gets typed by mistake. Currently this code solves the problem of anybody mistakenly deleting the cell contents.

Tried 'Data Validation' UI option to Reject Input, but miskently deleted cells will remove the validation and allow the user to type any other content.

```
function onEdit() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('range');
  range.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.setValue(e.oldValue?e.oldValue:null);
  e.source.toast('No Changes Allowed');
}
```

This won't work on large range edits like pastes since we only have the oldValue for the upper left corner.